# Redirect to page not working and not found codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to redirect to other page in my project, I recently put anything required in view and controller but when login it shows **404 Page Not Found**

below it's the code on the Auth controller :

```
 if ($userdata['tipe'] == 99) {
  redirect('admin');
} else if ($userdata['tipe'] == 88) {
  redirect('guru');
} else if ($userdata['tipe'] == 55) {
  redirect('piket');
} else if ($userdata['tipe'] == 77) {
  redirect('sekretaris');
} }
```

**P.S : The "Guru", "Admin", and "Sekretaris" successfully redirected, but when I add "piket" shown the error 404**

And here's the code on controller :

```
 public function index()
{
  $id = $this->session->userdata('id_user');

  $this->load->view('backend/layouts/wrapper', [
  'content' => 'backend/piket/home',
  'title'   => 'Beranda',
  'profile' => $this->user_m->profile($id),
  'userdata' => $id
], FALSE); }
```

Can you tell me the error of my code?

Comment: Do you need to leverage `base_url()` with your solution?  What happens if you write a full path -- just as a sanity check?  Do you have any redirecting happening in your routes.php file that might be causing problems? I probably wouldn't use an if-elseif-else block for the redirects; it would be cleaner and more modern to use `match()` or a lookup array to determine the correct redirect destination.

Comment: can you give me the example of the code? others are good but since I added "piket" it not work mick

Comment: I don't know if you have a class or method called `piket` in your project.  There are insufficient details to help you.

Comment: I can explain furthermore in linked if you don't mind...

Comment: Is there a proper route named 'piket' or a class named 'piket'?